# Setting a Window setVisible(false) without closing it and just to add things to make it Visible a millisecond later

Tags: java, constructor, window, frame, repaint

I have a class Window which looks like this:

```
public Window(int w, int h, String title, Game game) {

    this.game = game;
    game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
    game.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(w, h));
    game.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(w, h));

    frame = new JFrame(title);
    menu = new MainMenu();
    frame.add(menu);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(w,h);

        // frame.add(game); 

    frame.setVisible(true);


    /*
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    gs.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
    */
}
```

So the problem I have is , that I want to add the menu first ,which works well ,and as soon as my start button is clicked ( i programmed this in another class all working fine)
,it should start my game.

To start the game i want to add the the game

```
//frame.add(game)
```

,when the button is clicked .
Other words I want to use like without creating a new object window again.
So i want to call the constructor ,like repainting to do that !How do I repaint the window as soon as the boolean got changed ,without influencing the other code lines :/
For example

```
if(MouseInput.inMenu == true){
  frame.add(game);
  game.start();
}
```

EDIT:(30.03.2014 10:49)

I found out that if i add my game

```
frame.add(game);
```

I have to set my Window not visible , and then i have to add it!

```
frame.setVisible(false);
frame.add(game);
game.start();
```

Then it works.The problem here is as soon as I setVisible false the window disappears, but I want it to just reload like that:

```
frame.setVisible(false);
frame.add(game);
frame.setVisible(true);
game.start();
```

How do I set my frame not visible without closing it.

Comment: It would probably be best to create a class extending JFrame, and calling the .repaint(); in the gamePanel when the boolean is said. Have a look at the MVC pattern :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem lies with the LayoutManager.
I suggest you add this to your constructor:

```
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

then in your listener do:

```
frame.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

(Are you using ActionListener?)

Comment: In what listener should i do                                                        frame.add(game,BorderLayout.CENTER);                                                                                                                   I don't use ActionListener sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned a button being pressed. That's usually handled by adding an ActionListener to the button.

Comment: I programmed the button as image and with mouseInput handling stuff with x and y!

Comment: Then it's a MouseListener?

Comment: yes but read the edit I found out something maybe u can help me with that

Answer (score 0):

```
        Window.frame.setContentPane( new JPanel( new BorderLayout() ) );
        Window.frame.add(Window.game);
        Window.frame.revalidate();
        Window.frame.repaint();
        MouseInput.inMenu = false;
        Window.game.start();
```

Solved :D